# Python xmltodict with multiple OrderedDictkeys

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, xmltodict

Is there any way to create xml output that given a multiple OrderedDict like this

```
data = OrderedDict([
    ...
    ('addresses', OrderedDict([
        ('address', OrderedDict([
            ('city', 'Washington')
        ])),
        ('address', OrderedDict([
            ('city', 'Boston')
        ]))
    ]))
])
```

When i try this xmltodict covers last address not both.

Comment: that is because you have like a key 'address' for both OrderedDict (city)...How you get this OrderedDict ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have 2 keys with the same name 'address'..then if you change the both like bellow (address1,address2)...you can access in both.For parse you can use xmltodict

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from json import loads, dumps
import xmltodict

data = OrderedDict([
    ('addresses', OrderedDict([
        ('address1', OrderedDict([
            ('city', 'Washington')
        ])),
        ('address2', OrderedDict([
            ('city', 'Boston')
        ]))
    ]))
])

print(json.loads(json.dumps(data)))

print(xmltodict.unparse((data)))
```

result :

[image]